# Select distinct values in a inner join

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query, and my desired output would be to get only the rows for each pin with the highest `time`:

```
SELECT id,pin,time,companyid
  from v20records
  inner join tabuti on v20records.pin = tabuti.altuti 
                   and tabuti.codemp = v20records.companyid 
                   and v20records.companyid = 7
```

This is my current result:

```
id          pin     time                    companyid   
124887051   9999    2018-08-06 11:36:22.000 7
124887052   9999    2018-08-06 11:50:57.000 7
124887053   9876    2018-08-06 14:01:27.000 7
124887054   9876    2018-08-06 14:03:14.000 7
```

And this is my desired result:

```
id          pin     time                    companyid   
124887052   9999    2018-08-06 11:50:57.000 7
124887054   9876    2018-08-06 14:03:14.000 7
```

I have tried to use distinct and get the max time of each one but with no sucess. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An efficient method (with the right indexes) uses a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.time = (select max(t2.time)
                from t t2
                where t2.pin = t.pin
               );
```

The right index is on `(pin, time)`.

Another common method uses window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by pin order by time desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```